# Invalid command name ".!editspeakers.!canvas.!frame.!entry"

Tags: python, json, tkinter

When my program is compiled via pyinstaller I run into this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "editSpeakers.py", line 67, in <lambda>
  File "editSpeakers.py", line 52, in autoUpdateSpeakers
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 3043, in get
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!editspeakers.!canvas.!frame.!entry"
```

I presume this is a tkinter problem but I have no idea how to fix it and it only shows up when ran via pyinstaller not when ran via the IDE

Code Snippets:

```py
    def populate(self):
        speakers = main.openSpeakers()
        speakersList = sorted(speakers.items())
        numRows = len(speakers) + 3

        for i in range(numRows):

            self.key = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=20, fg="blue", font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
            self.value = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=20, fg="blue", font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
            self.key.grid(row=i, column=0)
            self.value.grid(row=i, column=1)

            EditSpeakers.entryList.append([self.key, self.value])

            try:
                self.key.insert(0, speakersList[i][0])
                self.value.insert(0, speakersList[i][1])
            except IndexError: pass

    def autoUpdateSpeakers(self, root):
        speakers = dict()
        try:
            for key, value in EditSpeakers.entryList:
                if key.get():
                    speakers[key.get()] = value.get()

            with open("speakers.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(speakers, f, indent=4)

        except Exception as e: print(e) ## << Error happening here
        finally: root.destroy()
```

You can find my full code [here](https://github.com/College-Kings/autoTranscriber)

Comment: Remove the `try` and find out the exact error code and error line.

Comment: @CoolCloud Updated original post

Comment: Basically the error means you are destroying the widget and still trying to use them. I think `root.destroy()` is the problem.